# JasperReports issue with permission on iOS 12

Tags: java, ios, jasper-reports, export-to-pdf

In my project i have to work on jasper reports to generate dynamic pdfs, one of the requirement is that the user is not allowed to copy text from the pdf but is allowed to print, so the following code was added as shown below

```
JRPdfExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
exporter.setParameter(JRPdfExporterParameter.IS_ENCRYPTED, Boolean.TRUE);
exporter.setParameter(JRPdfExporterParameter.IS_128_BIT_KEY, Boolean.TRUE);
exporter.setParameter(JRPdfExporterParameter.PERMISSIONS, new Integer(PdfWriter.ALLOW_SCREENREADERS | PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING));
```

Which does what is supposed to on chrome, firefox and iOS 11, but on iOS 12 the user is allowed to copy text again.
So i tried to set different permissions such as not allow to print, which works but can't print the document at all, which is against the requirements.

i also tried to negate the permission like this, which doesn't work

```
exporter.setParameter(JRPdfExporterParameter.PERMISSIONS, new Integer(~PdfWriter.ALLOW_COPY | PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING));
```

Should i set any different types of permission or is this a problem from the iOS side?

Comment: Try to set also the PROPERTY_OWNER_PASSWORD, I guess since no owner password iOS consider the user owner not user.

Comment: I answered this other similar question https://stackoverflow.com/q/56786900/5292302, consider to also remove your deprecated code and use the SimplePdfExporterConfiguration. Let me know if that still does not work on iOS (but other plat-forms), since it almost seems lie iOS is not respecting the user permissions.