# How to disable options as printing in generated PDF file?

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-pdf

When I generate a PDF with jasper reports I don't want the user to be able to print it.

Is there some option to make it from the code or does it only depend on the program which visualize it (web browser,adobe etc.).

Comment: @Noblesse I will edit the question it's about jasper report, exporting to pdf, hence setting encryption, user and owner permissions. Actually we got another 2 hours ago, I'm not sure if they are related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56783822/jasperreports-issue-with-permission-on-ios-12

Comment: configuration.setPermissions(PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING); if i remove it,printing will be disable what do you think?

Comment: I have posted an answer how to do it in jasper report, choose 1 method, it's important that you encrypt your pdf before with owner password, then you can set permissons, allow printing will not disable printing :), you need ALLOW_SCREENREADERS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achive this both by using jrxml properties or setting values to the [`SimplePdfExporterConfiguration`](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/export/SimplePdfExporterConfiguration.html) if you are exporting from java.

To protected your pdf document (hence in this case disallow printing), first thing you need to do is to encrypt it and be sure that you have nessary libraries for encryption in classpath see [How to configure PDF encryption in JasperReports Server 5.6.1](https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/how-configure-pdf-encryption-jasperreports-server-561)

**jrxml properties**

```
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.encrypted" value="true"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.128.bit.key" value="true"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.owner.password" value="12345"/>
```

*or*

**java code**

```
SimplePdfExporterConfiguration configuration = new SimplePdfExporterConfiguration();
configuration.setEncrypted(true);
configuration.set128BitKey(true);
configuration.setOwnerPassword("1234");
```

> Note we are setting owner password not user password, hence user will be allowed to open without.

### Now set the user permissions

[`net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.permissions.allowed`](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html#net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.permissions.allowed)

In your case I guess you only like to allow screen readers, if you like to also allow COPY or other actions (see link above) add these with `|` to your properties

**jrxml property**

```
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.permissions.allowed" value="SCREENREADERS"/>
```

*or*

**java code**

```
configuration.setPermissions(PdfWriter.ALLOW_SCREENREADERS);
```

> **Notice:** it is up to the reader/application to respect the permission, hence a developer can always open and do what they want with any PDF document. As example iText contains a flag `unethicalreading`, if you set it to `true`, you will be able to have owner access to these documents without knowing the password.

Comment: it works with this:configuration.setPermissions(PdfWriter.ALLOW_SCREENREADERS); Thank you!

Comment: @АлександърВелчев It works if the reader respects it :), I have edit so you can see if how to modify if you also like to allow COPY. Thanks for the "accept"